# Centered floating logo stuck on right only in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a fluid width site with a logo centered in the header area. The logo stays in the center regardless of the window size. Works in all browsers except ie9. In ie9 it is stuck on the right. If I could get it stuck on the left that would be an ok compromise but the right will not do. My best guess is that ie9 does not support the css code:

`.logo {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    }
    .logo img {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        display:block;
        }`

Here is the website http://www.cyberdefenselabs.org/

Anyone know a workaround for ie9 that will not affect other browsers or involve drastic recode?

Comment: I see the same display in FF18.0.1 as IE9 on Windows 7 x64. The logo (CDL_lgo1.png) is to the right, unless I narrow the window in which case it pops to the centre in both browsers and the "HOME CAPABILITIES" etc. menu disappears.

Comment: Are you saying the menu disappears completely??? And is not replaced by a different drop down menu? If so, yikes. This was originally a template I reworked. The main blue menu shows up on my browser test as still being there but I am using Adobe Browser labs and it only shows me a static page so I cannot test for things like what happens when I resize the window.

Comment: Now I do see a drop-down menu appear at the top when I reduce the width of the browser window, and it looks and behaves the same in IE9/W7x64 as FF18.0.2. The logo is centred in both cases. Did you re-work the menu, or did I not see it before because of the unexpected behaviour of it popping up to the top?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.social-header-wrap` element contains floating elements that are not properly cleared. Add this style:

```
.social-header-wrap {overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This one worked! The only thing I cannot tell is if it is still floating and moving as the window size changes. I am using Adobe Browser labs to see how it looks in IE9 and alas it shows me a static image of the site screen.

Comment: But It should still work just fine right? Just double checking.

Answer (score 0):

The person above is correct - you have floats that are not properly cleared.
But you should sort out your layout before making style changes as you have the same main menu 3 times but with 1 of them hidden and 1 (the first one) with white on white links.
Simply removing the first main menu (the div with the class "social-header-wrap") also solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this started as a template and my understanding was that the double menu's were for when it is shrunk down to the size of a phone. I made the top one white because I did not want it to show if the site is on a bigger screen thus showing 2 of the same menu. I am new to flexible sites so starting with a template was nice is some respects but also added more work in other ways of course :)

Comment: Since I am new to flexible layouts please advice if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
margin:auto;
```

you should say

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Get rid of margin-left and -right and change to margin:0 auto;

Also the containing element needs to be text-align:center which you undo by putting text-align:left in the element you are centering.